# Tableau aggregate several entries in one dimension (clustering)

Tags: cluster-computing, tableau-api, dimension

I have a very basic example where I have 10 different names whose age I want to compare.

So let's say "Name" is the Tableau dimension, and "Age" is the measure.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a comparison among a single individual and the rest of the 9 (averaged). Is there a way to create a cluster of  2 or more entries in the "Name" dimension?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use the "Set" functionality in Tableau.

1. Create a Set of 1 for the individual you are interested (By clicking and selecting Set from the tool-tip menu)
2. The resultant set created would be: In - for the selected individual Out - for everyone else
3. You can now use the Table Calculations on the Set to calculate the differences etc.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to put Name on the row shelf, select the names you want to group together and then click on the paper clip icon to group them. You can then right click on the long generated name and choose the alias command to pick a good name for your list of "everybody else"

There are more elaborate approaches if you want others to easily switch which name is singled out without having to edit the group. Experiment with parameters and calculated fields for that. But the easiest way to start is with Tableau's group feature